# @media is working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have my media queries at the bottom of my styles, I'm trying to make my grid be 50% of the screens width, however the 50% media query never seems to fire on a phone (iPhone 6s) however will on a browser re-size and I'm not sure why.

```
/* Media Queries*/
/* Max Width 1250px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 761px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .boxes {
        width: 33.3%;
    }
}

/* Max Width 750px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 760px) { 
    .boxes {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Max Width 500px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
    .boxes {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of your `meta` tag with the name of `viewport`?

Comment: I haven't set one, never played with viewports before

Comment: @JosephMarikle I added one and it worked, ty!

Comment: Here is a simple tutorial on them, I found it quite useful when I got into media queries: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

Comment: Yes, be wary of device resolution vs css pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[Here's the MDN article on viewport meta tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: Cheers dude, I never thought to add one!

Comment: @MattHammond Glad I could help. :)